# Indices have failed me - how can I optimize this SQLite query?

Tags: sqlite

I need some help optimizing the following query:

```
SELECT
kd2c.id as _id,
kd2c.literal as kanji
FROM
kd2_character as kd2c
JOIN krad_components as kcom ON kcom.kanji_fk = kd2c.id
WHERE kcom.radical_fk IN (1, 2, 3, etc...)
GROUP BY kd2c.id HAVING count(distinct kcom.radical_fk) = <number of integers in WHERE clause>
ORDER BY kd2c.freq IS NULL ASC, kd2c.freq, kd2c.id
```

The query itself (regardless of the number of fk's in the `WHERE` clause) takes 0.04 seconds to run, which is a long time relative to all of my other queries that take around 0.0003 seconds. I ran an `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` against the above statement and received the following:

```
# | selectid | order | from | detail 
1   0   0   0   SCAN TABLE kd2_character AS kd2c USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (~1000000 rows)
2   0   1   1   SEARCH TABLE krad_components AS kcom USING COVERING INDEX idx_krad_components (kanji_fk=? AND radical_fk=?) (~9 rows)
3   0   0   0   EXECUTE LIST SUBQUERY 1
4   0   0   0   USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
```

I'm pretty sure the script takes so long because of that initial `SCAN TABLE`. If that's the case, how can I get rid of it? I thought creating an index on `kd2_characer.id` would help things along, but it didn't have any noticeable effect on execution time.

How can I improve this query? Is there a better way to structure my `GROUP BY`, since it's probably the source of the `SCAN`?

Answer (score 0):

When SQLite joins two tables, it uses a nested loop join, i.e., it goes through all the records of one table, and looks up correspondig record(s) in the other table.
This is faster if many of the first table's records get filtered out by some `WHERE` condition before they must be joined, and if the second table has an index on the joined column.

For this particular query, SQLite has estimated that using `kd2_character` as the outer table in the loop is faster (because you have a single index that can be used for lookups in both `kanji_fk` and `radical_fk` columns).
This might or might not be actually true.

Try running [ANALYZE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_analyze.html) once to get more accurate estimations.

You can force SQLite to use a particular join order by using [CROSS JOIN](http://sqlite.org/optoverview.html#crossjoin); check if this makes a difference:

```
...
FROM krad_components AS kcom
CROSS JOIN kd2_character AS kd2c ON kcom.kanji_fk = kd2c.id
WHERE ...
```

(This optimization is dangerous if the database's contents eventually change so that the other join order would be faster.)

Comment: Changing the `JOIN` to a `CROSS JOIN` had no appreciable affect on execution time - the only thing that changed was an additional "USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY". `And I ran `ANALYZE` on the whole database. Just like you said, that "(~1000000 rows)" turned into a more accurate "(~13108 rows)". Thanks for pointing that out, it's way more useful to know more realistic numbers.

Comment: Some further testing revealed that it's the *ORDER BY* that's causing the slowdown. I created a new index with both `kd2_character.id` and `kd2_character.freq` but the query still needed to use a B-TREE for sorting.